# Insert statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert

I have strange problem related to SQL Server 2005

When I try to insert into table

```
insert into IDName
VALUES (101 , 'AA'),
       (301 , 'BB')
```

I receive this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

There is no problem, if I insert records one by one.

EDIT:
Thanks for reply guys.... but this script works in other installation of sql server 2005... I think it is some setting issue but i do not where... if you could help

Comment: Yes, that's because SQL Server **2005** doesn't support this feature! That was a new feature in the **2008** version.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 does not support that insert syntax; you would either need

```
insert into IDName 
SELECT 101 , 'AA'
UNION ALL SELECT 301 , 'BB'
```

or

```
insert into IDName VALUES (101 , 'AA');
insert into IDName VALUES (301 , 'BB');
```

Answer (score 4):

This syntax was introduced in SQL Server 2008. So upgrade, or use the more verbose:

```
INSERT dbo.IDName(column1, column2)
  SELECT 101 , 'AA'
  UNION ALL SELECT 301 , 'BB';
```

Some additional changes:

1. [Always use the schema prefix when referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
2. [Always specify the column list for an `INSERT`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
3. [Always use semi-colons to terminate statements](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)